# Making a procedure in Toad Oracle to run a query n times using parameters (X or Y or else)

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, procedure, toad

I have this code:

```
SELECT tableA.CODE,tableA.CREDIT, Q1, Q2, Q3, CountedStk, SystemStk
FROM
(
    SELECT table1.CODE as CODE, table1.credit as CREDIT, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q1 + Q2 - Q3 CountedStk
    FROM
    (SELECTstockurp.code as CODE, stockurp.credit, stockurp.quantity as Q1, reportenableurp.qty as Q2
    FROM stockurp JOIN reportenableurp 
    ON stockurp.code = reportenableurp.code and stockurp.credit = reportenableurp.credit 
    WHERE stockurp.ndate = '20150930' and reportenableurp.ndate = '2015-09-30')
    table1
    JOIN
    (SELECT accountid, credit, count (recharge.credit) as Q3
    FROM recharge
    GROUP BY accountid, credit) table2
    ON table1.CODE=table2.accountid
    AND table1.credit=table2.credit
) tableA
JOIN
(
SELECT stockurp.code as KODE, stockurp.credit as KREDIT, stockurp.quantity as SystemStk
FROM stockurp
WHERE stockurp.ndate = '20151001' )
tableB
ON CODE=KODE and CREDIT=KREDIT
WHERE CountedStk <> SystemStk
```

This code yields the comparison of the quantity from the counted stock (the stock for the N day) and system stock (the stock for N+1 day). In this example, the counted stock date is 20150930 and the system stock date is 20151001.

What I want to do is to :

1. Make a procedure so the ndate can be replaced by a parameter (lets say X).

Maybe like this:

```
   ON stockurp.code = reportenableurp.code and stockurp.credit = reportenableurp.credit 
        WHERE stockurp.ndate = X and reportenableurp.ndate = X)
        table1
        JOIN
```

Yep I know, the stockurp.ndate and reportenableurp.ndate is in different format, thus I need to convert the reportenableurp.ndate to char first.

And

```
FROM stockurp
WHERE stockurp.ndate = X+1 )
tableB
```

2. Also maybe a parameter to declare the starting date and end date so that the query run automatically according to the parameter. (Example: if I put start date 20151001 and end date 20151030, the procedure will run the query 30 times for each date and gives the result in one go)

How can I make the procedure to run this process? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write the procedure, but I'll describe what you do.

Define a local variable of type `date`:

```
declare
   v_date date;
```

Set the variable to a date:

```
v_date := date '2015-09-30';
```

Then write the relevant parts of the code as:

```
WHERE stockurp.ndate = to_char(v_date, 'YYYYMMDD') and
     reportenableurp.ndate = to_char(v_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

and

```
WHERE stockurp.ndate = to_char(v_date + 1, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Then -- and very importantly -- get everyone involved with the data to understand the importance of using the appropriate types for columns.  Dates should be stored as dates, not as strings.